# how to debug c++ in subprocess.check_call with VSCode

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-code

I wanna use VSCode to debug the program which is consisted of python and C++ language. The program start with python. When it runs to the function subproess.check_call, next step it will run with C++. But when I keep to single-step debug, the program is running but not step into C++. I need to see the C++ language in this program because the kernel code was made by C++.
The C++ process is called by function subprocess.check_call. How to debug it?

```
    try:
        logger.debug("Running: " + " ".join(cmdline))
        subprocess.check_call(cmdline)
```

Comment: Would you please edit your question and add the definition of `subprocess.check_call`? Anyway, assuming it executes a new process, it looks like the easy approach to debug this process is to add a sleep (maybe 10 seconds) and then while the process starts and pauses in the sleep you attach the C++ to the running process.

Comment: You do not have one program here.  Your Python code and your C++ code are two entirely different programs running in two different processes.  If you want to run your subprocess in a debugger, you need  to start a C++ debugger.  You CAN do that through `subprocess`, depending on which operating system you are using.

Answer (score -1):

First, on your `launch.json` needs to add two parts, one for Python and the other for C.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Attach",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/python", /* My virtual env */
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When you add a breakpoint on the line entering C, manually switch the launch to continue execution:

[image]

You can refer to this [case](https://nadiah.org/2020/03/01/example-debug-mixed-python-c-in-visual-studio-code/) for detailed adjustment.

Comment: No, you have missed the point.  He is not calling C++ code from Python.  He is invoking a separate C++ process.  The link you showed is for an entirely different case.